# Triggering one lambda to another using C# .net

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have two lambda. One is written in java and one is in .net. I just want to trigger the lambda(java) from .net.

Below is the code I used to trigger the lambda

```
        var awsLmabdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("fileGuid", fileGuid);
        InvokeRequest Ir = new InvokeRequest
        {
            FunctionName = "FunctionName",
            Payload = dict.ToString()
        };
        awsLmabdaClient.InvokeAsync(Ir);
```

I checked the cloudwatch logs in AWS but it is not showing any error or exception as per the code is concerned. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A more easy approach is : use cloudwatch metrics to invoke second lambda function

1. Every time a lambda is invoked, logs are maintained in cloudwatch
2. You can use those logs as trigger to your second lambda function

you can follow the documentation to do so :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of .ToString() provided by base System.Object class will actually give you complete name of the type including the namespace.

In you case Payload will have some thing like "System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary[system.String, System.String]",
Whereas you would want to have JSON string.

you could try playing around with something similar to this.

```
    {
        FunctionName = "FunctionName",
        Payload = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict).ToString())
    };
```

Your payload will now be "{\r\n  \"fileGuid\": \"fileGuid\"\r\n}" .

And have the Input parameter as JObject for the Lambda being called and get your values from JObject.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked for me. PayloadJObj is a Jobject

```
using (AmazonLambdaClient client = new AmazonLambdaClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2))
        {
          var request = new InvokeRequest
            {   FunctionName = "YourLambdaFunctionName",
                InvocationType = InvocationType.Event,
                Payload = PayloadJObj.ToString()
             };

           var response =  client.InvokeAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 

        }
```